# PHP - Can i count the amount of rows in my db and execute something when it exceeds 10 rows?

Tags: php, mysql

I've built a web app that uses SNMP to log all errrors that happen on my network device. Thats done. However, i want to know if there is a way in PHP to count the records in the database and let it for example mail me if there are more then 10 errors for that specific item.

Lets say i have network device A, and i log a certain activity such as harddisk space. What i want is that if that certain activity reaches more then 10 rows in my database, it automatically sends me a mail.

The mail part shouldn't be a problem, but i'm not sure how to count those rows in my sql database especially because i log way more activitys and network devices. I want this done for all the activity's i log.

My log table has these columns:

- ID
- Network Device
- Activity
- Error
- Timestamp

What is the best way to approach this? 
All help would be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 1):

You can get the rows in the DB like this:

```
$sql="SELECT id FROM myTable";
if ($result=mysqli_query($con,$sql))
{
    $rowcount=mysqli_num_rows($result);
    if($rowcount > 10)
    {
            //Do your mailing
    }
}
```

The other more efficient approach would be:

```
$result=mysqli_query($con, "SELECT count(*) as total from myTable");
$data=mysql_fetch_assoc($result);
$total = $data['total'];
if($total > 10){
    //Do your mailing
}
```

Comment: I edited my question as i might have been a little unclear. I have a bunch of network devices and a bunch of different processes i log on those network devices. If for example; network device a with the hdd storage process has more then 10 errors i want to automatically let it mail me. I want this done for all the processes on all the network devices. Your code would only count all the processes based on id but it doesn't watch the network devices. Hope you understand me a bit better now.

Answer (score 0):

Set your task in the crontab that will monitor your table for every hour (or your desired schedule).

Example:

index.php

```
    $result=mysqli_query($con, "SELECT * from yourtable GROUP BY network_device HAVING count(*) > 10");

   while ($row = mysql_fetch_assoc($result)) {
       //send email to you.
   }
```

In cron tab (for linux):

Open terminal and type crontab -e 
Set your schedule every hour. This will scan your table every hour and send execute your code.

```
0 * * * * php -f /file/to/index.php
```